# NtQuerySystemInformation SystemHandleInformation wont give correct return size

Tags: windows, winapi

```
    PSYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION HandleInfo = NULL;
    ULONG HandleInfoLength = 0;
    
    ...
    
    result = NTQSI((SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS)0x10, NULL, 0, &HandleInfoLength);
    if (result != 0xC0000004) {
        printf("OmmeSearchProcessHandle - NTQSI output is unexpected! Expexted : 0xC0000004 Result : 0x%x\n", result);
        return NULL;
    }

    printf("system handle info length : %i\n", HandleInfoLength);
    SIZE_T HandleInfoRegionSize = HandleInfoLength;
    result = NTAVM((HANDLE)(-1), (PVOID*)&HandleInfo, 0, &HandleInfoRegionSize, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(result)) {
        printf("OmmeSearchProcessHandle - NTAVM failed with result : %x\n", result);
        return NULL;
    }

    result = NTQSI((SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS)0x10, (PVOID)HandleInfo, HandleInfoLength, &HandleInfoLength);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(result)) {
        printf("OmmeSearchProcessHandle - NTQSI failed with result : %x\n", result);
        printf("system handle info length : %i\n", HandleInfoLength);
        return NULL;
    }
```

The code above produces [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvcXL.png). Somehow the first NtQuerySystemInformation call doesnt give the correct return size, anyone have any idea about this? And then, i stubled upon [this](https://github.com/adamkramer/handle_monitor/blob/master/handle_monitor.cpp#L397) on Github, `NtQuerySystemInformation won't give us the correct buffer size`, is this a common knowledge that NTQSI SystemHandleInformation wont give the correct return size?

Comment: It seems that way from googling, though I haven't tested it myself. In any event, it's not enough to call twice. You're gonna need to loop since the handle list could grow between calls.

Comment: I think it is, from my friend's experience too, they said that "it only returns the size of one handle information for your first call, but calling it twice like you do is not ideal anyways, because even if the system creates a single handle between your first and second call it would also fail, so you need to call it in a loop, check the return value and increase the buffer allocation size for every iteration"

Comment: Testing this for myself, at least on Windows 10 21H2, the API works as expected with the exception of the first call for Length = 0; in that case, it returns a required Length of 32.

Comment: This is probably a undocumented call so you get what you deserve! Not all the NtQuery function classes know the size, you just have to loop until you got it all.

Comment: why you decide that NtQuerySystemInformation  not return correct size ? of course it return correct size. another task - your code is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ReturnLength` value returned by a call to `NtQuerySystemInformation` with `SystemHandleInformation` does not necessarily represent the required buffer size to hold the entire system handle information - or more precisely, it depends on the input buffer size if it does or not (refer to [this](https://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/km/ntoskrnl/api/ex/sysinfo/query.htm)). Calling the function twice like in your example is not a good practice even if it returned the expected buffer size, because the required size could change in between your first and second call. A working example could look like this:

```c
void GetHandleInfo()
{
    PSYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION handleInfo = NULL;
    DWORD size = 0, required = 0;
    NTSTATUS handleInfoStatus;

    do 
    {
        if (handleInfo)
        {
            fpExFreePool(handleInfo);
            handleInfo = NULL;
        }

        size = required + PAGE_SIZE;

        if(!(handleInfo = fpExAllocatePool(NonPagedPool, size)))
            goto Done;

    } while ((handleInfoStatus = fpZwQuerySystemInformation(0x10, handleInfo, size, &required)) == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH);

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(handleInfoStatus))
        goto Done;

    //The handle info is available here

Done:

    if (handleInfo)
        fpExFreePool(handleInfo);

    return;
}
```

Comment: no, code is wrong by desin. and very not efficient. where you use `required` ?

Comment: I left out `ReturnLength` because it may return unreliable information. See the screenshot posted by OP, first it returns required size `32` even though it is not correct.

Comment: no, it always return reliable information

Comment: also need use SystemExtendedHandleInformation instead SystemHandleInformation

Comment: Refer to this: https://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/km/ntoskrnl/api/ex/sysinfo/query.htm. The value of `ReturnLength` is dependent on the input buffer size. This is not very clear and may lead to confusion (especially since this is undocumented) so I chose to ignore this value - at the cost of efficiency.

Comment: no, all is absolute clear. `ReturnLength ` return current required size for buffer, except case you pass 0 size as input - it return size for single entry. simply need not pass 0 size as input. from another size your `size += 1024;` is very not effieent. huge

Comment: From my understanding, it is not dependent on 0 being passed as buffer size, but on the size of the "formally defined structure" (info for one handle).

Comment: if you pass not 0 size for input buffer - you got actual size required for store all handle info

Comment: Interesting, in this case Geoff Chappell's documentation so wrong. I have adjusted my code accordingly.

Comment: for what use 2 different variables - `size` and `required` when we can use single ? why is 2 calls to `fpExFreePool` when can have only 1 ?

Comment: 2 calls to `ExFreePool` to avoid nested code - its a personal choice. 2 variables to make it easier to understand/read the code in my opinion - the compiler will optimize this away anyways.

Comment: In your code, `cb` describes 2 things at the same time (requested buffer size and actual allocated buffer size) which is not ideal for readability, but its only an opinion and does not affect efficiency at all, so no need to discuss this further.

Comment: different people have different ideas about readability. for me visa versa much more redable use sigle variable and such code

Answer (score 1):

the handle count in system is very volatile. so between 2 calls to NtQuerySystemInformation handle count in system can incremented and require more size. you need call NtQuerySystemInformation in loop. and need use `SystemExtendedHandleInformation` instead `SystemHandleInformation`

```
NTSTATUS TestHandles()
{
    NTSTATUS status;
    ULONG cb = 0x400000;
    do 
    {
        union {
            PVOID buf;
            PSYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION_EX pshie;
        };

        status = STATUS_NO_MEMORY;

        if (buf = LocalAlloc(0, cb += 0x1000))
        {
            if (0 <= (status = NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemExtendedHandleInformation, buf, cb, &cb)))
            {
                if (ULONG_PTR NumberOfHandles = pshie->NumberOfHandles)
                {

                    PSYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO_EX Entry = pshie->Handles;
                    do 
                    {

                    } while (Entry++, --NumberOfHandles);

                }
            }

            LocalFree(buf);
        }

    } while (status == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH);

    return status;
}
```